# AdMob,after banner click,device back button not working

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have integrated admob in my android game of cocos2dx,but the problem i am facing is with back button.Once user click on bannar ads and try to press back button of device the back button method is not getting called.

The admob inegration is as below:-

```
adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);


        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    adView.setBackgroundColor(0);
                    addContentView(adView,adParams);
        _appActiviy = this;
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }
                });
            }

        }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And the back button integration is as below through jni:-

```
_appActiviy.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(_appActiviy).setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?").
                setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Log.d("", "ShowRateUsAndQuitDialog ");
                        ((Cocos2dxActivity)_appActiviy).finish();
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                UntanglePro.showRateDialog(getContext(),null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Same issue here.

Comment: yet no success!,are you able to do?